# Is this a valid proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Q: Prove that $m^2 = n^2$ iff (if and only if) $m = n$ or $m = -n$

I began by assuming that the condition m = n or m = -n could be restated as |m| = |n|.
Next, I rewrote that as $\sqrt{m^2} = \sqrt{n^2}$. I wrote out my argument as such:

1) $|m|  ≠ |n|$

2) $\sqrt{m^2} ≠ \sqrt{n^2}$

3) If $m^2 = n^2$, then $\sqrt{m^2} = \sqrt{n^2}$

4) Proof by contradiction

Comment: I think what you have done is correct.

Comment: You proved the "only if". In order to prove the "if", you can simply show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$m^2 = n^2 \Leftrightarrow m^2 - n^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow (m+n)(m-n) = 0 \Leftrightarrow m= \pm n$

Comment: @Benjanim. Thanks for edit, I was looking in help for that symbol.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good proof.

1. You only proved that if ${m^2} = {n^2}$, then $|m|= |n|$. You must also prove that if $|m|=|n|$, then $m^2=n^2$
2. Even the proof you made lacking, since you have not shown that $\sqrt{m^2}\neq \sqrt{n^2}$ follows from $|m|\neq|n|$. You should elaborate on that point.

Comment: I already did part 1 and was more sure of its correctness, so I asked about the part I was unsure of. Part 2 I always thought of as an accepted fact (I plugged it into WolframAlpha to verify and it said it was true). How can part 2 be proven? Is it actually true?

Comment: What you are proving is an accepted fact on its own, so you must prove it rigorously. Usually, in these kind of excercises, you are only allowed to use what you already know from class (not just "it is an accepted fact"). For example, you can prove that if $m>n>0$, then $m^2=m\cdot m > m\cdot n > n\cdot n = n^2$ follows from the axioms of real numbers.

Comment: One more hint, especially when doing elementary proofs like this one: if you think something is "obviously" true, then the proof of it should be simple and you should write it down (or know exactly were to find it).